# Error CS1704 in aspnet mvc razor and dnx 1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr x86

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-asp.net-mvc, dnx

I'm getting in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 the error:

> *error CS1704: An assembly with the same simple name 'Kendo.Mvc' has already been imported. Try removing one of the references (e.g.
>   'Kendo.Mvc.dll') or sign them to enable side-by-side.*

I cleaned the cache, temporary files asp net, I tried it with another version of Kendo, I updated and reinstalled dnx and tested with x86 and x64. I do not know what else to do.

My project.json is:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "EPPlus": "4.0.5",
    "eVC": "1.0.0-*",
    "eVDTO": "1.0.0-*",
    "eVR": "1.0.0-*",
    "Kendo.Mvc": "2016.1.112",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-rc1-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-rc1-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0-rc1-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-*",
    "NPOI": "2.1.3.1"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "deployment": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --ASPNET_ENV production --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost/eV",
    "web2": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls=http://localhost:5000",
    "gen": "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
    }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],

  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],

  "scripts": {
    "postrestore": [ "npm install", "bower install" ],
    "prepare": [ "gulp copy" ]
  }
}
```

And in Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        //services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddCaching(); // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache
        services.AddSession();
        services.AddKendo();
    }
```

Comment: Have you possibly added the library not via nuget? what happens when you remove the nuget package?

Comment: I tried all possible combinations with and without nuget. It solves nothing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague has found the answer. It is a temporary solution (workaround) but works.

In Visual Studio 2015 > Tools > Options > Debugging > General we have marked options:

-Use Managed Compatibility Mode

-Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators

[image: Visual Studio 2015 > Tools > Options > Debugging > General]

Answer (score 0):

I think if you remove all the relevant references (from nuget or not), clean your project and than add the reference again via nuget, it will solve your issue .